# Ubuntu 23.04 Alt-Tab Delay Removal

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

How can I speed up or remove the **Alt-tab delay** as the gnome extension is not compatible with **Ubuntu 23.04**

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2741/remove-alttab-delay-v2/